# DevExpress, convert DataGridView to GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview, devexpress

I have a class called `classA` which the constructor used to accept a `DataGridView` argument.

Like so:

```
public class classA {
    readonly DataGridView thisClassData = default(DataGridView);
    public classA(DataGridView someData){
        Init();
        thisClassData = someData;
    }
}
```

I am making a call elsewhere like this:

```
classA classA_obj = classA(otherDataGridView.SelectedRows[0]);
```

I have now converted everything to use `DevExpress`, so in `ClassA`, I have changed `DataGridView` to `GridView`, however, I do not know how to pass in the selected rows as GridView. Can someone show an example of how this can be achieved?

Comment: `otherDataGridView.SelectedRows[0]` return the value of type `DataGridViewRow`. It's unclear how you are using this: `classA classA_obj = new classA(otherDataGridView.SelectedRows[0]);` because it does not compiles. What the type of `otherDataGridView` variable?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a DataGridView to a GridView.
What you can do, is get the data (or part of the data) of the DataGridView and set the DataSource property of the gridView.
Something like this

```
List<classA > list = new List<classA >();
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
        list.Add((classA )dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].DataBoundItem);

gridview.DataSource = list;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to convert a DataGridView to a DevExpress GridView. You should do everything from scratch. Also, (DevExpress) GridView.GetSelectedRows() method returns the row handles of selected rows.